# How could we calculate the coefficient of a PI controller (ki - kp) which regulates the voltage of the DC bus link of a three-phase inverter?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, transfer-function

From my calculations I arrived at a non-linear equation :

$$ C\frac{dV_{dc}}{dt} = 3e_q\frac{I_q}{2}V_{dc} - \frac{V_{dc}}{R_{dc}} $$

I have calculated the operating points which are $I_q = 9.58A$, $V_{dc}=400V$ and $R_{dc} = 65.6$
but I got stuck on the next step to find the transfer function of this equation .

[image]

Comment: You need to linearize your function....depending on your numerical software this is often a oneliner...StateSpaceModel, Series in mathematica or ssm in matlab for example....or if you’re going by hand, taylor series.

Comment: Once linearized, you can do the laplace transformation on your ODE

Comment: THINK YOU FOR YOUR ANSWER ,

Comment: NOW I FOUND THE TRANSFER FUNCTION THE NEXT STEP IS TO CALCULATE THE COEFFICIENT OF THE pi CONTROLER HOW CAN I CALCULATE THEM

Comment: There are dozens of ways, ask a new question with your new transfer function with the qualities you want your controller to have, please don’t be lazy and type correctly.